# Allow logon locally option grayed out

Tags: group-policy, login, windows-10

We have a Domain Controller running on windows2012R2.

All local computers are on Windows10.

When i try to login to one of the client computer with Domain User Credentials i get an error

[image]

What could be the issue?

I tried to add users to " Allow log on locally " Policy on Local computer with Local admin login 
but im unable to add users or groups

[image]

Is there any work around?

please suggest.

Comment: Probably UAC; use "Run as administrator" to launch the policy editor. Anyway, there already is "Everyone" listed... you can't really add much more.

Comment: i tried running with administrator even , no Luck. . 
if this is not the solution, what could be the issue  "The sign in method . . . . "  :/

Comment: Seems like a user/computer GPO setting more than a local computer.  Might want to check the GPO settings on the server more than on the local computer.

Comment: May be , Do you have any idea which GPO may cause this thing? #Brandyn

Comment: You can use `gpresult` to find what GPOs are applied to the computer.

Comment: [This is the GPO](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc957048.aspx).  I believe there is also a computer setting equivalent that can prevent local logon from specified computers.  You'd have to check your GPOs to see if the setting has been configured on any of them.

Comment: Is this Windows login error related to GPO(Allow logon locally)?
If it is then i'll close this Question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to manage this element via Group Policy Management. Czerw11 did a good write up of the process of using Group Policy Management to update this on your domain controllers via the Default Domain Controller Policy, you can extend this to your client policy as well.

https://czerwsup.wordpress.com/2014/11/05/allow-log-on-locally-add-new-user-greyed-out-fix-via-domain-controller-policy-settings/

Summary Steps:

1. Admin Tools
2. Group Policy Management
3. Navigate through your domain to Default Domain Policy in your case (not Default Domain Controllers Policy as in the example)

**To improve this answer, the best practice is to not edit the Default Domain Controllers Policy, but to create a GPO with these policies changes and assign it to the narrowest OU you need to affect the servers. If you edit the Default Policies you remove all of the default permissions.**

4. Computer Configuration -> Policies -> Windows Settings -> Security Settings -> Local Policies
5. User Rights Assignment
6. Double Click on Allow Log On Locally and add your users